# Scrape a web and get a value that changes with a javascript funtion

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to log in and scrape a value from this page: `https://adf.ly`, specifically the amount of views my links have. I have achieved to login and get to the page where the value I want appears, but the problem is that this value isn't loaded with the page, it is loaded later using a javascript function. The code I have used is the following one:

```
 <?php
    function getViewsAdfly(){
        $cookiePath = './cookieAnuncios.txt';
        $url = "https://login.adf.ly/login";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiePath);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiePath);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $token = urlencode(getMatchToken($result));
        $email = urlencode("my email");
        $password = urlencode("my password");
        $parametrosPost = "token=" . $token . "&bmlUrl=&bmlType=&bmlDomain=&bmlFolder=&dest=&response=&challenge=&email=" . $email . "&password=" . $password;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametrosPost);
        curl_exec($ch);

        $urlViews = "https://adf. ly/publisher";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlViews);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        $resultViews = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return getMatchViewsAdfly($resultViews);
    }

    function getMatchToken($result){
        preg_match_all("(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"token\" id=\"token\" value=\"(.*)\" />)siU", $result, $matchesToken, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        return $matchesToken[1][0];
    }

    function getMatchViewsAdfly($result){
        preg_match_all("(<h4 id=\"summary-views\">(.*)</h4>)siU", $result, $matchesViews, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        return $matchesViews[1][0];
    }
 ?>
```

If I use this code, the page shows a message saying "There has been a problem while fetching the stats. Please refresh the page and try again." and the `<h4 id=\"summary-views\"></h4>` which contains the data I want to scrape only shows "loading...". I think that the javascript method which charges the real number on the  cointainer isn't running correctly. Do I have to add any curl setopt which is missing so that the javascript runs? How can I manage to get the real data I want to scrape after it gets loaded on the container?

**EDIT:**

The javascript saves the data on `s[0]`. Any way I can get what is stored there?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#edit_link').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: AdFly.awesomeBrowser() ? 420 : 450,
                    width: AdFly.awesomeBrowser() ? 550 : 580,
                    modal: true,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    resizable: false
                });

                $('#edit_advert_type').chosen();

                $('#charts-tabs, #links-tabs').easytabs({animate: false, updateHash: false, tabs: "nav > ul > li"});

                $('#charts-tabs')
                        .bind('easytabs:after', function (event, $clicked, $targetPanel, settings) {
                            PublisherIndex.updateCountries();
                            $('ul.earnings').addClass('displayNone');
                            if($targetPanel.selector == '#charts-tab-4'){
                                $('ul.earnings.popads').removeClass('displayNone');
                            }else{
                                $('ul.earnings.simplelinks').removeClass('displayNone');
                            }
                        });

                $('#report_date').chosen();
                $('#report_date').change(function() {
                    $('.timePicker').removeClass('current');
                    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
                    PublisherIndex.renderStats();
                    PublisherIndex.updateLinks();
                });

                $('.timePicker').click(function() {
                            if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'all_time') {
                        alert("Sorry all time stats are currently disabled.");
                        return;
                    }

                    $('.timePicker').removeClass('current');
                    $('#report_date').parent().removeClass('current');
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                    PublisherIndex.renderStats();
                    PublisherIndex.updateLinks();
                    PublisherIndex.renderSummary();
                    return false;
                });

                $('#findlink').keypress(function(event) {
                    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                    if (keycode == '13') {
                        PublisherIndex.updateLinks();
                        $('#search_clear').show();
                    }
                });

                $('#links-tabs').bind('easytabs:after', function(event, $clicked, $targetPanel, settings) {
                    PublisherIndex.updateLinks();
                });

                PublisherIndex.getAnnouncements();
                //PublisherIndex.renderSummary();
                PublisherIndex.renderStats();
                PublisherIndex.renderLinks();

                $('.monthlyEarningsSummarySelector').click(function() {
                    $('.monthlyEarningsSummarySelector').removeClass('current');
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                    PublisherIndex.renderStats();
                    PublisherIndex.renderSummary();
                    return false;
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Little hack for getting the URL Groups.
                $('#edit_group').html($('section.shorten select[name="group"]').html());
                $('#edit_group').chosen();
            });

            var PublisherIndex = {
                countriesDt: null,
                countriesLength: null,
                referralsDt: null,
                earningsChart: null,
                graphData: null,
                popupsChart: null,
                popupGraphData: null,
                earningsSummary: null,
                tokenCSRF: null,
                linkId: null,
                updateCountries: function() {
                    var oTable = $('#charts-tab-2').find('table').dataTable();
                    var table_height = 419;
                    var num_rows = this.countriesLength;
                    var row_height = $('section.dashboard section.charts table tr').outerHeight();
                    if(num_rows<10){
                        num_rows = 10;
                    }else if(num_rows>20){
                        num_rows=20;
                    }
                    var required_height = parseInt(table_height) + (parseInt(num_rows)-10)*parseInt(row_height);
                    $('section.dashboard section.charts nav.menu').css('height', parseInt(required_height));
                    $('section.dashboard section.charts .data .panels').css('height', parseInt(required_height)+8);
                    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
                    oSettings._iDisplayLength = num_rows;
                    oTable.fnDraw();
                },
                getAnnouncements: function() {
                    ApiCaller.getAnnouncements(AdFly.USER_TYPE.PUBLISHER, $('#announcements'), false);
                },
                renderSummary: function() {
                    $('ul.earnings:not(.totals)').css('visibility','visible');
                    $t = $('.timePicker.current, #reportDateWrapper.current');
                    var key = null;
                    var copy = null;
                    key = $("#report_date").val();
                    var i = 1;
                    copy = $('.chzn-container-single .chzn-single span').eq(3).text();
                    copy = copy.substring(0, copy.length - 5);
                    var views = 0;
                    var earnings = 0;
                    var referrals = 0;
                    var total = 0;
                    $.each(this.graph.data,function(i,day){
                        views+=parseFloat(day.views);
                        earnings+=parseFloat(day.earnings);
                    });
                }
            }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't use curl to execute javascript like you're hoping.

Comment: But the javascript code is contained on the web I `curl_exec($ch)`. Shouldn't it run with the rest of the page? @Scuzzy

Comment: No, because all you're downloading is a plain old raw html document at this stage. Compared to a browser, which downloads the html document and runs it through its engine to parse it into it's document object model and apply rules and run other scripts, curl is part one of that process, not the whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl doesn't execute JS. You have two options:

1. **Use some technique which executes the JS.** That's hard in PHP and you should not try it. (If you want to do it, then you'll need a JS engine in PHP, like [V8](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php)). Try to use instead [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). You could create a web-service which runs the JS code server-side ([Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)) and fetch then the data with PHP via an API.
2. **Get the data the same way as the JS functions gets it.** There are only two options:

   - The data is being loaded after the page was delivered. Then they must use a HTTP request. Find this request and imitate it.
   - The data is written down somewhere on the delivered page, but has not yet been shown. Maybe it's stored in a JS variable, which the function calls. *(I mean JS code which has been constructed server-side and includes the variable already)*

Good luck!

Comment: It's the second option of number 2. Javascript code is something like this: 
`this.earningsSummary[key] = {views:views, earnings:earnings, referrals:referrals, total:total};
...... more code .......
var s = [this.earningsSummary[key].views, this.earningsSummary[key].earnings, this.earningsSummary[key].referrals, this.earningsSummary[key].total];
$('#summary-views').html(Globalize.format(s[0], 'n0'));`
so the data is saved on s[0] and then loaded by jquery $("#containerID").html(...). Is there any way I could get the data stored there?

Comment: Sorry code doesn't shows clearly here. I edited the original post with that same code.

Comment: It must be set somewhere, open the code of the page and search with Ctrl + F for a value. Let's say, if you have a link with 127 clicks, search for it. It must be somewhere in the code. You can't get the value of the variable, because you haven't executed the JS code.

Comment: It isn't saved that way I think. I edited again the post, I posted what I think is the important part of the JS code, specifically it is the var PublisherIndex > function renderSummary > var views. I think the data saves on that var. What should I do to get the int number saved on that var? Thanks for your effort and patience.

Comment: I just found another script label where it executes the code I just said and get some values. It doesn't appear the value I was looking for, but it appears a total value I can take and then do the mathematics operations to get the value I want. Thanks for all, I will mark you as correct answer :) One last question, can I find with preg_match_all the data in the `$result = curl_exec($ch)` if it is into a script label or it doesn't mean any problem?

Comment: Everything perfect, managed to get the data without any problem. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.